# Making scroll appear after handlebars template appended

Tags: html, css, datatables, handlebars.js

So I'm appending handlebars templates so that my final html looks sort of like this

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="results1">
    <table id="results2">
    <table id="results3">
</div>
```

Now, when I append there are a lot of rows per table, and I want a scroll bar to appear.

I've tried

```
.container{
    overflow : -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    overflow-y : scroll; 
}
```

but this doesn't make a scroll bar appear.

Also, I'm using dataTables.js after the tables have been appended(when I take this out, the above css still doesn't work).

What should I do?

OK. I figured it out.

So my html had

```
<div class= "parentContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <table id="results1">
        <table id="results2">
        <table id="results3">
    </div>
</div>
```

when I added that CSS to the parent it totally worked. Why is that the case?

Comment: Does the `.container` have a max size specified?

Comment: no it does not have a max size specified

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/fgV4x/) with data that appends.

I suspect that your problem has something to do with the height of the container not being specified. Make sure you are either setting `height` or `max-height` in the css.

If you have any more problems, post a jsFiddle of the problem.

Have fun!